# Linq and left join

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have the following models:

```
public class UserPage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class UserPageSetting
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; } = true;
    public bool Published { get; set; } = true;
    public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }

    public virtual UserPage UserPage { get; set; }
}
```

`UserPage` collection has 5 records, `UserPageSetting` has 1 record. I need to have a result with 5 records and default values for unexisting records.

I try to do it:

```
var list = (from userPage in _dbContext.UserPages
           join userPageSetting in _dbContext.UserPageSettings on userPage.Id equals userPageSetting.PageId
           into gj
            from subUserPageSetting in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where subUserPageSetting.UserId == userId
           select new UserPageSettingDto { Active = subUserPageSetting.Active, Modified = subUserPageSetting.Modified, Id = userPage.Id, Icon = userPage.Icon, IsSelected = userPage.IsSelected,
               Name = userPage.Name, Path = userPage.Path, Published = subUserPageSetting.Published
           }).ToList();
```

but in result I see only one record. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Here's your problem: `where subUserPageSetting.UserId == userId`.  
The `UserId` comes from `UserPageSetting` - and since it only has one record, the `where` clause will filter the result of the join to that one record (if it fits the `userId` you've supplied).

Comment: Use left join to get records from UserPage that are not related with UserPageSetting

Comment: @ZoharPeled how to do it?             `var filter = from userPageSetting in _dbContext.UserPageSettings where userPageSetting.UserId == userId select userPageSetting;`

            `var list = (from userPage in _dbContext.UserPages
                       join userPageSetting in filter on userPage.Id equals userPageSetting.PageId
...).ToList();` does not work too...

Comment: That depends on what you actually want to get in your `list`. Do you want all instances of `UserPage`? do you want to execlude instances of `UserPageSetting` that contain a different UserId from the one you've passed into the query?

Comment: You need left outer join: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins

Comment: @ZoharPeled Right, I didn't read carefully. Thanks.

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or INNER JOIN ON that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL after an OUTER JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to do a left join and create a default `UserPageSetting` if the join fails. This will return 5 records; 1 for each `UserPage`. One of these will have a successful join indicated with `Active = true`

```
void Main()
{
    var inner = new List<UserPage> {
        new UserPage { Id = 1, Name = "One" },
        new UserPage { Id = 2, Name = "Two" },
        new UserPage { Id = 3, Name = "Three" },
        new UserPage { Id = 4, Name = "Four" },
        new UserPage { Id = 5, Name = "Five" }};

    var outer = new List<UserPageSetting> {
        new UserPageSetting { UserId = 1, PageId = 1, Active = true, Published = true }};

    var joined = inner
        .GroupJoin(outer, i => i.Id, o => o.PageId, (i, o) => o
               .Select(x => new { Inner = i, Outer = x })
               .DefaultIfEmpty(new { Inner = i, Outer = new UserPageSetting {UserId = i.Id, PageId = i.Id, Active = false, Published = false } }))
        .SelectMany(x => x)
        //.Where(x => x.Outer == -1) -- include if you only want to see the join misses
        ;

    foreach (var x in joined)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"UserPage({x.Inner.Id}, {x.Inner.Name}) joined to UserPageSetting({x.Outer.UserId}, {x.Outer.Active})");
    }
}
```

This will output the following:

```
UserPage(1, One) joined to UserPageSetting(1, True)
UserPage(2, Two) joined to UserPageSetting(2, False)
UserPage(3, Three) joined to UserPageSetting(3, False)
UserPage(4, Four) joined to UserPageSetting(4, False)
UserPage(5, Five) joined to UserPageSetting(5, False)
```

Comment: `var joined = _dbContext.UserPages
    .GroupJoin(_dbContext.UserPageSettings, i => i.Id, o => o.PageId, (i, o) => o
           .Select(x => new { Inner = i, Outer = x })
           .DefaultIfEmpty(new { Inner = i, Outer = new UserPageSetting { UserId = i.Id, PageId = i.Id, Published = false } }))
    .SelectMany(x => x).ToList();`

Comment: returns: ArgumentException: Expression of type &#x27;System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TmsApi.Core.UserPageSetting]&#x27; cannot be used for return type &#x27;System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[&lt;&gt;f__AnonymousType0`2[TmsApi.Core.UserPage,TmsApi.Core.UserPageSetting]]&#x27;